# Integral calculation: residue theorem or it is useless?

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I would like to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^2+ax},$$
where $a$ is a parameter which defined as the integral converges. I would like to try use residue theorem. Thus, I start from the analysis of integrand poles:
$$(1-x)^2+ax=0\rightarrow x_{1,2}=1-\frac{a}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2-4a}.$$
But then I do not understand which contour I should use to evaluate the integral....

Comment: Why do you want to evaluate the integral by residue theorem? It can be done by elementary means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locating the poles is (very) useful, but the residue theorem not so much.
 Let us assume that $\nu,\bar{\nu}$ are such that
$$ (1-x)^2+ax = (1-\nu x)(1-\bar{\nu}x), $$
i.e. solutions of $\nu+\bar{\nu}=2-a, \nu\bar{\nu}=1$. Then
$$ \frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^2+ax}=x-\frac{ax^2}{(1-x)^2+a}=(x-a)+\frac{a-(2a-a^2)x}{(1-\nu x)(1-\bar{\nu}x)} $$
decomposes as
$$ (x-a)+\frac{1}{\bar{\nu}-\nu}\left[\frac{2a-a^2-a\nu}{1-\nu x}-\frac{2a-a^2-a\bar{\nu}}{1-\bar{\nu}x}\right] $$
whose integral over $(0,1)$ equals
$$ \frac{1}{2}-a+\frac{a}{\bar{\nu}-\nu}\left[(\nu+a-2)\bar{\nu}\log(1-\nu)-(\bar{\nu}+a-2)\nu\log(1-\bar{\nu})\right]$$
as soon as $\nu,\bar{\nu}\not\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\text{Re}(\nu),\text{Re}(\bar{\nu})<1$.

Comment: However, I am interested in the case $a>4$, so, as I understand, in this case $\nu$ & $\bar{\nu}$ are reals. Is it possible to use analytic continuation of Yours answer?